# Pandas fails at numexpr check inside exe script made with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller, numexpr

I made a Dash web applications from which an .exe was created by using PyInstaller. The app loads without problems but at calling a function it suddenly stops. The problem seems to lie at the fact that numexpr library is not installed (pandas check _NUMEXPR_INSTALLED fails), eventhough by running the script in python doesn´t generate any problem.

[cmd error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDhK8.png)

I´m using pandas 1.0.1, PyInstaller 3.6 and Python 3.7.7
I have already tried the following:

- Downgrading pandas from 1.0.5 to 1.0.1 due to problems with PyInstaller
- Adding pandas path to the PyInstaller .spec file

  ```
  def get_numpy_path():
    import numpy
    numpy_path = numpy.__path__[0]
    return numpy_path
  dict_tree = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
  a.datas += dict_tree
  a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'pandas' not in x[0], a.binaries)
  ...
  ```
- I Installed numexpr, yet the version was 2.7.1 and in pandas.compat_optional version 2.6.2 is defined, hence it also caused some problems and didn´t work. pip didn´t allow me to install any version of numexpr

Any ideas how to overcome this problem to have a functional .exe?
PS: the app also uses numpy, scypi and sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same problem by

1. Explicitly installing numexpr (`conda install numexpr`)
2. Importing explicitly in the python code: `import numexpr`